# How to activate Instant Run in AndroidStudio 2.0

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

Android studio 2.0 introduced instant run facility, its not working for me,
I know 2.0 is in the preview channel

Anybody tried 2.0 with instarun facility?

Comment: follow these steps http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/instant-run

Comment: What's New in Android Studio (Android Dev Summit 2015) video demoing it https://youtu.be/fs0eira2pRY?t=20m52s

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Instant Run is enabled by default for projects built using Android Gradle Plugin 2.0.0, or later. To update an existing project with the latest version of the Gradle plugin, go to the Settings dialog:

On Mac, click **Android Studio → Preferences**
On Windows and Linux, click **File → Settings**

In the Settings/Preferences dialog, go to **Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run.** 
Click the Update Project link. When prompted, click OK.
[image]
If the the Update Project link does not appear, your project is already **up to date.**

#### Using Instant Run

To first run your app, click **Run ‘app’**  (or **Debug ‘app’** ). Android Studio will run your app by compiling, dexing, packaging and installing an .APK file, and launching the app. After your app has launched, a **small, yellow thunderbolt will appear with the Run ‘app’  button (or Debug ‘app’  button)**. This indicates that the Instant Run feature is ready.

Clicking **Run ‘app’ (or Debug ‘app’) again will start an Instant Run** and your changes are pushed to the connected device within a few seconds.

To terminate the running app on your device, click **Stop ‘app’** .

Answer (score 3):

Instant Run is enabled by default on newly created projects and it can be turned on for existing apps in the project settings at Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run. Build scripts will have to be updated to use v2.0.0-alpha of the Gradle plugin. As always, this is still very new and may not be completely stable.

Comment: I've had consistent problems with Instant Run such as being unable to cast an Activity to a new listener interface until I terminate the process and rebuild the project. IMO It's wasted me far more time than it's saved. Thanks for letting me know how to disable. I'll try it again in a couple months, but it's really frustrating right now.