# Android Studio: Taking long time to install apk

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I am using wifi adb to load app into mobile device from Android Studio. I run this script to connect to my mobile device.

```
#!/bin/sh

adb tcpip 5555
adb connect 192.168.1.237:5555
```

Previously I did not have any problem but recently it takes a few minutes to install apk.

Too much logs are generated and I have no idea which part is the cause. The error appeared most frequently is

> E/SecUISvc: Error initializing local socket: -1

Comment: did you enabled instant run

Comment: Enable instant run that should work a bit faster. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34173500/how-to-activate-instant-run-in-androidstudio-2-0

Comment: I have turn off instant run in setting.

Comment: Refer to this link. Worked for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38004831/8273992